# Stripe Checkout Price error - Invalid Integer

Tags: checkout, stripe-payments

I have a stripe account and am using the test API keys.

I have created a Plan  with following info -

```
{
  "amount": 995, 
  "created": 1418800758, 
  "currency": "usd", 
  "id": "c06e1791-1c6a-45fe-9c26-8f0c07dda967", 
  "interval": "month", 
  "interval_count": 1, 
  "livemode": false, 
  "metadata": {}, 
  "name": "Pro2", 
  "object": "plan", 
  "statement_description": null, 
  "statement_descriptor": null, 
  "trial_period_days": null
}
```

I'm using checkout.js in my project. 
Once all the data is filled and we click on pay for the above plan, it raises an error 'Invalid Integer 994.999999999'.

This error is not raised for the $9.94, $9.96, $29.95 and other values tried by me.

Is this a checkout bug or something to do with my settings ??

Screenshot of the error -

[image: Stripe error message]

jsfiddle reproducing the error - http://jsfiddle.net/f30z9uc6/2/

Comment: Where is the error happening exactly? On Stripe Checkout when creating the token or on the server when Creating a charge or a subscription? Could you share your code ? Are you trying to calculate the amount and then maybe a rounding error issue?

Comment: The error occurs on checkout before creating the token. And the price is static.Fetched from the stripe plan.

Comment: the amount `995` works as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ykh2dh7/  there must be something else going on. Can you show a URL where this happens? You must have something parsing the price and setting `data-amount` to the wrong value

Comment: @koopajah I was able to reproduce the error in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f30z9uc6/2/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem here is a floating point error in Javascript. If you look at this updated version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f30z9uc6/3/) you'll see what's happening and how I fixed it. You need to round the result of your calculation to ensure you end up with an integer:

```
var amount = Math.round(9.95*100); // gives 995
```

To read more about Javascript and floating point arithmetic you should look into [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

Comment: This was just useful for me with Stripe amounts. Works like this if anybody needs it: `Math.round(TotalPrice.toFixed(2)*100)`

Comment: Does rounding make +/- in price ammount @MatthewBennett ?

Comment: Yes and no. I mean you might lost a tenth of a cent but that's not something that seems important. You can always round up if it matters.

Comment: Seems to be working so far, @codemilan, at least with all of the prices I've checked it with. Stripe has recently raised a couple of decimal errors, but I think that's related to something else, not this code.

Comment: @MatthewBennett this is a Perfect solution thank you

Answer (score 4):

Before you send the variable to strip you have to round to max. 2 decimals. So it will work.

Why?
Because Stripe multiplies your value with 100 and the result has to be an integer - otherwise you get the error message.

Answer (score 3):

If currency is USD, the value is in cents not dollars, so 2, is 2 cents, 50, is 50 cents. 
Apparently.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same issue in stripe account before passing the value to the backend just convert your value from object to the simple integer like this

```
enter code here

 const TotalItems = data
 .map(function(item) {
  return item.total;
})
.reduce(function(curval, newval) {
  return curval + newval;
});
```