# Stripe throws invalid integer error

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am unable to charge the amount $49.99 in stripe. I am going through the following links but nothing workout

[Stripe Checkout Price error - Invalid Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025804/stripe-checkout-price-error-invalid-integer)

[Stripe Rails: Invalid integer: 1.06](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837952/stripe-rails-invalid-integer-1-06)

I would like to charge the amount as it is. I don't want to round off the payment

```
 stripe.charges.create({
    // Charge the customer in stripe
// amount: req.query.amount,
    amount: 49.99,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: req.customer
  }).then(function(charge) {
    // Use and save the charge info in our db
    var successTransaction = {
      stripeId: charge.customer,
      transactionId: charge.id,
      amount: charge.amount,
      currency: charge.currency,
      message: charge.outcome.seller_message,
      paidStatus: charge.paid,
      summary: charge
    };
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Stripe allow only integer value in price so need to change your price (amount) into cent by (*100 ) so now your code amount is 499 and in stripe sdashboard you see the 49.99 for more details check the link :

https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges

> In other words, Stripe's API always takes smallest supported unit as input (without need to configure anything), for example, amount of 1 means 1-Cent not 1-Dollar.

Comment: @leekei: I am happy its useful for somebody.

Comment: A great and concise explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following method as it will help you to use the decimal value as the amount and display the same amount in the invoice and during payment.

amount: `Math.round(49.99 * 100)`

Comment: You deserve a cent! :)

Comment: i did 19.98 instead of 19.99 and worked

Answer (score 0):

Stripe allows integer value as price, if you want to charge $49.99 then multiply it with 100.

Smallest price unit allowed by stripe is cent.

`599 cents = $5.99`