# Stripe: parameter_invalid_integer, New to PHP

Tags: php, debugging, integer, stripe-payments

I am debugging my code. I am no genius at PHP and need some help to decipher what I declare as the parameter if it is not an integer...

Can anyone help?

```
{

  "error": {

    "code": "parameter_invalid_integer",

    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",

    "message": "Invalid integer: 1.13",

    "param": "amount",

    "type": "invalid_request_error"

  }
```

$app->post('/createCharges', function() use ($app) {
        $response = array();

```
    $json = $app->request->getBody();
    $data = array(json_decode($json,true));

    $amount = $data[0]['amount'];
    $source = $data[0]['source'];
    $appointmentid = $data[0]['appointmentid'];


    \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_KEY);

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $source,
        "description" => "test order from ios"
    ));
```

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: my thoughts are this is a simple fix... or am I mistaken?

Comment: It may be a simple fix, but we can't see your code unless you post in your question.

Comment: should I send the whole class? I have so much code I don't know what to send...

Comment: The message explicitly says that you have an invalid integer 1.13 in the parameter amount. You may want to look at that point of your code and share this piece of information where you mount the parameters.

Comment: Try to shrink your code, so that you have a minimal (non) working example and then post this code (with error message).

Comment: Does the above code help? @FelippeDuarte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripe throws invalid integer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453090/stripe-throws-invalid-integer-error)

Answer (score 7):

With Stripe, the `amount` property of a `Charge` is always an integer in the smallest unit of a currency (cents for USD).

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-amount

So to charge `$1.13` you'd need to make sure the `amount` that you pass in `\Stripe\Charge::create` is `113` rather than `1.13` --- if your front-end is passing a decimal value a simple `*100` should get you the value you need here, e.g. `$amount = (int)($data[0]['amount'] * 100);`

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an aged post nevertheless I'm willing to leave an answer to help someone else.

Stripe always receive `integer` as `$cent` value. So, whenever you tend to create a charge or payout or transfer or any type of transaction through Stripe you are bound to set `cent` value as an integer.
So to charge `$5010.458` you must have to convert it to `cent` as an integer which mustn't contain any fractional/decimal components.

You have several options to do so. For instance:

```
$amount = (number_format($amount, 2, '.', '') * 100)
```

If you charged as `cent` you may use: `round(), ceil(), or floor()` PHP functions to get nearest `integer` value.
Also, you can use **casting:*** `(int) $amount` or `intval($amount)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

> (int)($request->amount * 100),

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => (int)($request->amount * 100),
        'currency' => 'AED',
        'description' => "booking"
    ]);
```